# Opentok stream.hasAudio gets false when leaving Chrome tab on iPhone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opentok

When going to a different tab in Chrome on iPhone (not closing it), the publisher's `stream.hasAudio` value becomes *false*. It becomes *true* again only when returning to the stream tab. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent `hasAudio` from turning off?

This does not happen on Safari though or any desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how fix this in the right way, and what is your use case, but possible workaround could be (in pseudocode):

> if (isActiveTab && stream.hasAudio) { do your things }

**Edit**: might need to check for IOS mobile Chrome as well